# Pandas code for making a 2D list out of a list based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
lst = ['Mickey', 'Mickey Mouse', 'Donald', 'Donald Duck', 'Hansel', 'And Gretel', 'Hansel And Gretel'..........]

DF  Character           Numbers
4   Mickey Mouse        1.0
5   Donald Duck         1.0
6   Hansel And Gretel   2.0
....
```

I want the 2D list to be created like this. The code should group the field in DF and the one preceding it in the list if Numbers is 1, the field and the two fields preceding if Numbers is 2 and so on.

```
lst1= [['Mickey', 'Mickey Mouse'], ['Donald', 'Donald Duck'], ['Hansel', 'And Gretel', 'Hansel And Gretel'].....]
```

The grouping needs to be done based on the value of the Numbers field in the DF. If Numbers =1, then the corresponding character in the list and its one preceding field needs to be grouped, if numbers =2 then the corresponding character in the list and its two preceding fields need to be grouped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

lst = ['Mickey', 'Mickey Mouse', 'Donald', 'Donald Duck',
       'Hansel', 'And Gretel', 'Hansel And Gretel']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Character': {4: 'Mickey Mouse', 5: 'Donald Duck',
                                 6: 'Hansel And Gretel'},
                   'Numbers': {4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 2.0}})

lst_df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['words'])

merged_df = lst_df.merge(df,
                         left_on='words',
                         right_on='Character',
                         how='left')

# BFill Conditionally on value 
merged_df['Numbers'] = merged_df['Numbers'] + 1
m = (merged_df['Numbers']).notnull() & merged_df['Numbers']
g = m.iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
merged_df['Numbers'] = merged_df.groupby(g)['Numbers'] \
                           .apply(
    lambda x: x.bfill(limit=int(x.iat[-1] - 1)) if x.iat[-1] > 1 else x
) - 1

# Remove Any Values that weren't conditionally bfill-ed
merged_df = merged_df.dropna(subset=['Numbers'])

# BFill Character To Match
merged_df['Character'] = merged_df['Character'].bfill()

# Group and convert to List
out_lst = merged_df.groupby(['Character',
                             'Numbers'],
                            sort=False)['words'].agg(list).to_list()

print(out_lst)
```

Output:

```
[['Mickey', 'Mickey Mouse'], ['Donald', 'Donald Duck'], 
 ['Hansel', 'And Gretel', 'Hansel And Gretel']]
```

---

Ref: [Backwards fill dataframe column where limit of rows filled is based on value of cell, perhaps with bfill() and limit=x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62791218/15497888)

*Assumption: Character Names are unique. Each character in `df` appears once in both the `df` and in `lst`.